# The segue to a new NSViewController should show the new one on top of the old one covering the whole Window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I'm porting a game from iOS to MacOS. I know Apples Catalyst would be one option, but I don't want to go this way, because it makes a huge difference for my UserInterface if it is controlled by touch or a mouse.

In iOS I'm showing a new ViewController on top of the old ViewController. The background of the new ViewController is transparent.

Configuration was done this way:

[image]

Result looks like this (the new VC shows the Game Menu in the middle and all buttons of the background VC are deactivated):

[image]

How can I achieve the same for MacOS?

I tried this way:

[image]

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Change the settings on the window view controller and subclass NSWindow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to call `presentAsModalWindow(_:)` (which is the code equivalent of the "Present Modally" option). It doesn't provide for any customization of the window you're using to present the view controller in. What you likely want to do is simply call the `present(_, animator:)` call which allows you to present a view controller on top of another. I made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HQTpPV7KZY&t=13s) on creating custom animations using this call which probably will answer how you can achieve what you want here.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll check tomorrow. Many thanks for your answer

Comment: @Stefan Sure thing, let me know if it doesn't answer your question. Happy to help!